# Telerik EditableGrid errors

Tags: c#

In my view for my Editable Grid i'm getting errors about: "The name 'GridButtonTupe' does not exist in the current context" and "The type of namespace could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I have included all reference files, do you know what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, it seems that you need to be accessing 'GridButtonTupe' via FindControl("GridButtonTupe") in the code behind.

See this, for example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx (take a look at the default.aspx.cs example)

A code example of the issue would be helpful if this is not the answer.